# How to serialize an included object/property as a root?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I've got a tough problem. Let's say I have a class named `ObjectHost`, containing a property of type `BusinessObject`, which itself contains some properties (let's say a `Name` and a `Town` as strings).
The code would be :

```
public class ObjectHost
{
    public BusinessObject Data { get; set; }

    public ObjectHost()
    {
        Data = null;
    }

    public ObjectHost(BusinessObject ei)
    {
        Data = ei;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (Data == null) ? "null" : Data.ToString();
    }
}
```

When serializing, it will produce something like :

```
<ObjectHost>
  <Data>
    <Name>My name</Name>
    <Town>London</Town>
  </Data>
</ObjectHost>
```

Where I'd like it to be :

```
<Name>My name</Name>
<Town>London</Town>
```

as it is only an encapsulation object in my particular use (for some other purposes).

I tried using `XmlRoot` and `XmlElement` attributes but I didn't achieve my goal.

Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: How are you currently serializing it?

Comment: Actually, `ObjectHost` objects are properties of other parent objects, which are all serialized using an `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you are using XmlSerializer to serialize an Object.

You are passing in ObjectHost and want only properties of ObjectHost.BusinessObject to be emitted.

You can use one of the following approaches

1. Post processing of serialized data -> use XPath queries to get desired data

   ```
   /ObjectHost/Data
   ```
2. Customize serialize process: (This is little tricky)
   a) Implement IXmlSerializable
   b) Customize ReadXml, WriteXml, and GetSchema

   In the WriteXml, use XPath query, or other Xml methods (to get XmlNodes) and write only desired properties.
   This approach will be tied to particular data structure, and cannot be used for incompatible data structure.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the good way, but could you point me to some implementation guidelines for the WriteXml/ReadXml ? Actually they have an `XmlWriter`/`XmlReader` as method arguments, where the serialization should be done. I don't know exactly what type of "temporary XmlWriter" I should use to get the "Data" object serialized in, then move to the child nodes, and then extract them to put them into the original `XmlWriter` the `WriteXml` method gives me ...