# How to (de)serialize a type as a key for a property, but as the full POCO when it is the root object?

Tags: c#, serialization, redis, servicestack

I'm exploring using ServiceStack and Redis to persist documents in redis for a project. It would be neat (maybe) if I could have getters and setters in a document type that refer to other document types natively in memory, but as a scalar key when being (de)serialized, to reference the redis location of the property. Something like:

```
public class Sport
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RandomFactNumberOfPlayers { get; set; }
    // lots of other random properties about sport I don't want to duplicate in my player serialization
}

public class Player
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }
}
```

would serialize a sport and a player as something like:

```
{key: 'a', name: 'Football', randomFactNumberOfPlayers: 123456},
{key: 'b', firstName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Brady', sport: 'b'}
```

And when deserializing those records I would have the chance to look into my redis repository and fetch the key of b and deser it as a Sport and assign it to the sport property of my player instance.

I've looked a bit at JsConfig (De)serializeFn and Raw(De)serializeFn, and I had the thought that I could have my types derive from a (simple) base Document type, with a key, and (de)ser documents to and from string keys, but the issue that I see there is that the function will be called for both root instances and properties.

Is there any notion of custom property (de)serializer overrides in service stack? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just keep a string EntityId (specifically SportId) property?

Comment: Yep, I don't mind doing that, just don't like having to have to write a lot of duplicate get key, go to repository and load object code. Feels like we end up with these double entries - the Key property and the GetEntity method that gets the object based on the key. introduces more room for bugs and errors, more boilerplate.

Comment: looks like this is maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723302/how-to-serialize-an-included-object-property-as-a-root?rq=1

Comment: I'd prefer the loading of the object from an id (which has many sideffects i.e IO etc) to be quite explicit in my code instead of doing magic behind the serializer

Comment: seems reasonable. but... if I were to do go about designing this way, with a bit of magic, could I do it with servicestack?